# Apply QGraphicsColorizeEffect to a part of a QGraphicsSvgItem (only to the svg itself)

Tags: qt, svg, qgraphicsitem

I have a `QGraphicsSvgItem` subclass where I would like to modify the svg color. I want to use for that `QGraphicsColorizeEffect`, and it works great.

My items also have a custom selection rectangle, highlighted - similar to other item types.

When I apply the colorize effect, the highlight also turns to the same color...

I have tried to `setEnabled(false);` in paint but it seems to have no effect.

sample code:

> file mysvg.h

```
#ifndef MYSVG_H
#define MYSVG_H

#include <QGraphicsSvgItem>
#include <QGraphicsColorizeEffect>

class MySvg : public QGraphicsSvgItem
{
public:
    MySvg();
    ~MySvg();
    virtual void paint(QPainter* painter,
                       const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option,
                       QWidget* widget = NULL);
private:
    QGraphicsColorizeEffect* m_effect;
    void drawSelectionRectangle(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, const QRectF& rectangle);
};
#endif // MYSVG_H
```

> file mysvg.cpp

```
#include <QStyleOptionGraphicsItem>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QPainterPath>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QSvgRenderer>

MySvg::MySvg()
{
    m_effect = new QGraphicsColorizeEffect();
    m_effect->setColor(Qt::red);
    setGraphicsEffect(m_effect);
    setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable    |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable  |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);

    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, tr("Open Svg File"),
                     QString(), tr("Svg files (*.svg *.svgz)"));
    setSharedRenderer(new QSvgRenderer(filename));
}

MySvg::~MySvg()
{
    delete renderer();
    delete m_effect;
}

void MySvg::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem opt(*option);
    opt.state = QStyle::State_None;

    QGraphicsSvgItem::paint(painter, &opt, widget);

    //m_effect->setEnabled(false);  // no effect though seemed logical
    QRectF rectangle = boundingRect();
    if (option->state & (QStyle::State_Selected))
        drawSelectionRectangle(painter, option, rectangle);
    //m_effect->setEnabled(true);
}

void MySvg::drawSelectionRectangle(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, const QRectF &rectangle)
{
    painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::DotLine));
    painter->setBrush(QColor(255, 188, 0, 50));
    painter->drawRect(rectangle);
}
```

> file main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include "mysvg.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene s;
    QGraphicsView view;
    view.setScene(&s);
    s.setSceneRect(-50, -50, 500, 650);
    view.show();
    MySvg* svg = new MySvg();
    s.addItem(svg);
    return app.exec();
}
```

> file mysvg.pro

```
QT       += core gui svg
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = mysvg
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp \
           mysvg.cpp
HEADERS +=  mysvg.h
```

I have considered making a `QGraphicsSvgItem` a private member of the `MySvg` item - but the `MySvg` item has to do a lot of other things, and I don't know what to do with the renderer (who would own it...) - if I can figure out how to make a `QGraphicsSvgItem` subclass a member of the `MySvg` class, I can apply the colorize to the member and perform all other operations on the `MySvg` item...

Please help me figure a way to apply color to the svg, but not other drawing portion of the item.

**Edit** - I have tried to add a member item to the class and apply the colorize effect to the member - but it doesn't apply the colorize effect at all... The svg loads with all original colors.

Here is the code containing a member item:

> new mysvg.h

```
class SvgMember : public QGraphicsSvgItem
{
public:
    SvgMember (const QByteArray &content, const QColor& c);
    ~SvgMember ();
private:
    QGraphicsColorizeEffect* m_effect;
};

class MySvg : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    MySvg();
    ~MySvg();
    virtual void paint(QPainter* painter,
                       const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option,
                       QWidget* widget = NULL);
    virtual QRectF boundingRect() const;
    virtual QPainterPath shape() const;

private:
    void drawSelectionRectangle(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, const QRectF& rectangle);
    SvgMember * m_member;
};
```

> new mysvg.cpp

```
MySvg::MySvg()
{
    setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable    |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable  |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);

    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, QObject::tr("Open Svg File"),
                     QString(), QObject::tr("Svg files (*.svg *.svgz)"));
    QFile f(filename);
    f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
    QByteArray svgContents = f.readAll();
    f.close();
    m_member = new SvgMember (svgContents, Qt::red);
}

MySvg::~MySvg()
{ 
    delete m_member;
}

void MySvg::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem opt(*option);
    opt.state = QStyle::State_None;

    m_member->paint(painter, &opt, widget);

    QRectF rectangle = boundingRect();
    if (option->state & (QStyle::State_Selected))
        drawSelectionRectangle(painter, option, rectangle);
}

/*! \brief reimplemented to use member rectangle */
QRectF MySvg::boundingRect() const
{
    return m_member->boundingRect();
}

/*! \brief reimplemented to use member shape */
QPainterPath MySvg::shape() const
{
    return m_member->shape();
}

void MySvg::drawSelectionRectangle(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, const QRectF &rectangle)
{
    painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::DotLine));
    painter->setBrush(QColor(255, 188, 0, 50));
    painter->drawRect(rectangle);
}

SvgMember ::SvgMember (const QByteArray &content, const QColor &c)
{
    m_effect = new QGraphicsColorizeEffect();
    setGraphicsEffect(m_effect);
    m_effect->setColor(c);
    setSharedRenderer(new QSvgRenderer(content));
}

SvgMember ::~SvgMember ()
{
    delete renderer();
    delete m_effect;
}
```

What can I do to apply the colorize effect to the svg - but not to the selection rectangle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect is a feature of the base class `QGraphicsItem`. It is applied to the entire graphics item and all its children. So, everything that is painted inside the item is affected by its effect.

The selection rectangle should be painted outside of the SVG item object.
It can be achieved by enclosing `QGraphicsSvgItem` by the composite class `QGraphicsItemGroup`.

When a `QGraphicsItem` is added to `QGraphicsItemGroup` it becomes reparented. Thus the item is destroyed when the group object is destroyed. So, it is not needed to delete it manually. `QGraphicsItem` takes ownership of effect, so it is not needed to delete the effect object.

The following class `MyGraphicsItemGroup` works as you expect.

> Implementation "mygraphicsitemgroup.cpp"

```
#include "mygraphicsitemgroup.h"

#include <QGraphicsColorizeEffect>
#include <QGraphicsSvgItem>
#include <QStyleOptionGraphicsItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QFileDialog>

MyGraphicsItemGroup::MyGraphicsItemGroup()
{
    setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable    |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable  |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);

    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0,
        QObject::tr("Open Svg File"), QString(),
        QObject::tr("Svg files (*.svg *.svgz)"));

    QGraphicsColorizeEffect *effect = new QGraphicsColorizeEffect();
    effect->setColor(Qt::red);

    QGraphicsSvgItem *svg = new QGraphicsSvgItem(filename);
    svg->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
    addToGroup(svg);
}

void MyGraphicsItemGroup::paint(QPainter* painter,
    const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
{
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem opt(*option);
    opt.state = QStyle::State_None;
    QGraphicsItemGroup::paint(painter, &opt, widget);

    QRectF rectangle = boundingRect();
    if (option->state & QStyle::State_Selected)
        drawSelectionRectangle(painter, option, rectangle);
}

void MyGraphicsItemGroup::drawSelectionRectangle(QPainter *painter,
    const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, const QRectF &rectangle)
{
    painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::DotLine));
    painter->setBrush(QColor(255, 188, 0, 50));
    painter->drawRect(rectangle);
}
```

> Header "mygraphicsitemgroup.h"

```
#ifndef MYGRAPHICSITEMGROUP_H
#define MYGRAPHICSITEMGROUP_H

#include <QGraphicsItemGroup>

class MyGraphicsItemGroup : public QGraphicsItemGroup
{
public:
    MyGraphicsItemGroup();

    virtual void paint(QPainter* painter,
        const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget);

    void drawSelectionRectangle(QPainter *painter,
        const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, const QRectF &rectangle);
};

#endif // MYGRAPHICSITEMGROUP_H
```

Comment: Based on your explanation, my second implementation should have worked as well - since I set the effect on a `QGraphicsItem`, that is painted inside another (not a child). Yet the effect doesn't get applied at all. Using a group seems very awkward - and makes very difficult the implementation of the object, because I have to set the svg at different times after the construction, I have to be able to apply changes to the object, like color, transformations, and so on... Why would a group object allow members to have effects, while a normal object would not ?

Comment: @Thalia There is one big difference with your second implementation. If item is in group it is also added to the scene. Internally `QGraphicsItem` has private pointer to its scene. Many depends on that. In your solution the item has to parents and it is not attached to any scene. That solution is not harder than your second implementation. You can work directly with internal item and set all needed effect. `QGraphicsItemGroup` is just another `QGraphicsItem` that wraps your main object.

Comment: I will try to implement it now, and thank you for the solution. I still don't understand the part about adding the item to the scene, my member object should be painted as part of the big item... I had some bad experiences with `QGraphicItemsGroup` but perhaps in this particular case the group properties will not be a problem.

Comment: @Thalia The `paint()` function of items is triggered by `QGraphicsScene` for items that it owns (added as `s.addItem(svg)`). The scene calls `paint()` for items and also it call private effect functions. In your second solution the scene does not know about `SvgMember`. It calls `paint()` for `MySvg` and inside that paint you call `SvgMember::paint()`, but no one can call painting of the effect here. There is very strong dependency between `QGraphicsScene` and items that it owns.